# nmap ports scan closes udp socket on windows open by ipworks v4

Tags: windows, sockets, network-programming, udp, winsock

Upon receiving UDP packets from nmap (port scanner), UDP socket that were open by ivrworks (v4) is being closed without any notification.

Has anyone encountered such a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like ipworks closes socket upon empty udp packet. ipworks8 solved the problem